# SwiftUI background color change animation difference

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Question

The following view changes background color with animation.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isSelected = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isSelected.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Hello")
                .padding(50)
                .background(isSelected ? Color.red : Color.green)
        }
        .buttonStyle(NoHighlightButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

But when I enclose that button in NavigationView + ScrollView, the animation is gone.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isSelected = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Button {
                    isSelected.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Hello")
                        .padding(50)
                        .background(isSelected ? Color.red : Color.green)
                }
                .buttonStyle(NoHighlightButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference?

## Supplement

`NoHighlightButtonStyle` is for making the difference stand out disabling button highlight.

```swift
struct NoHighlightButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}
```

## Environment

- iOS 16
- Xcode 14.3.1

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I couldn't reproduce it in a simulator. But I have this animation difference in my production code. I will look for minimal  code that can reproduce the difference.

Comment: I found that NavigationView + ScrollView disable the background color animation. I will edit my question.

Comment: I revised my question.

Comment: Actually, I just realised you didn't even add `.animation(.default, value: isSelected)`. Adding that should create the animation. Now I wonder why it even worked when you didn't add the `ScrollView`...